# Xml file returning NonType traceback errror while parsing

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have been trying to parse an xml file using ElementTree.parse and I was getting NullType TraceBack Error. I know a lot of question has been asked about this same issue, but I noticed something about the xml file I was trying to parse. I noticed the xml file is different from the one I saw in the questions asked on these platform. Not that I have an idea of what a standard xml file should looked like but I am suspecting perhaps my file is the problem.

The file is gotten from archive.org and it is a file containing data from stackexchange. The file is included here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <row Id="-1" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2015-03-16T22:02:56.000" DisplayName="Community" LastAccessDate="2015-03-16T22:02:56.000" Location="on the server farm" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Hi, I'm not really a person.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I do things like&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention&lt;/li&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them&lt;/li&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted&lt;/li&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own suggested edits from anonymous users&lt;/li&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92006&quot;&gt;Remove abandoned questions&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;" Views="22" UpVotes="74" DownVotes="991" AccountId="-1" />
  <row Id="1" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T14:49:42.463" DisplayName="Adam Lear" LastAccessDate="2022-09-20T19:44:00.090" Location="New York, NY" AboutMe="&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Developer at Stack Overflow focusing on public Q&amp;amp;A. Russian Canadian working in the American idiom.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Once upon a time:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;community manager at Stack Overflow&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;elected moderator on Stack Overflow and Software Engineering&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;desktop software developer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Email me a link to your favorite Wikipedia article: &lt;code&gt;adam@stackoverflow.com&lt;/code&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="76" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="37099" />
  <row Id="3" Reputation="4186" CreationDate="2015-03-17T14:59:26.040" DisplayName="dfife" LastAccessDate="2022-03-01T21:34:56.797" WebsiteUrl="http://www.dustinfife.net" AboutMe="" Views="70" UpVotes="54" DownVotes="0" AccountId="136853" />
  <row Id="4" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2015-03-17T14:59:37.893" DisplayName="Conor Semler" LastAccessDate="2015-03-17T15:14:42.150" Views="3" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="5091225" />
  <row Id="5" Reputation="443" CreationDate="2015-03-17T14:59:56.080" DisplayName="Niall C." LastAccessDate="2023-04-01T03:09:46.917" WebsiteUrl="http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/22" Location="Portland, OR" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;I'm here because when I'm working on my house, I think of things that I'd like to make.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="2" UpVotes="28" DownVotes="2" AccountId="10331" />
  <row Id="6" Reputation="525" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:02:41.573" DisplayName="CoAstroGeek" LastAccessDate="2022-11-16T20:19:09.717" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Working in the space business in Colorado Springs for about 15 years with a focus on astrodynamics, orbit design, collision avoidance analysis and high performance computing.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="3" UpVotes="46" DownVotes="1" AccountId="3341901" />
  <row Id="7" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:06:07.907" DisplayName="Shog9" LastAccessDate="2022-08-23T21:09:17.643" WebsiteUrl="http://shog9.com" Location="Frontier, WA, USA" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Well, fancy seeing you here!&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I work for &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.enterprisedb.com/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;EDB&lt;/a&gt;, assisting a bunch of really skilled people share their PostgreSQL expertise and experience with the world.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Before that, I worked here - at Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange. Here, my duties &lt;em&gt;also&lt;/em&gt; involved helping a bunch of really skilled people share their knowledge. So you might encounter some posts from me which provide guidance and advice for the folks using this network of Q&amp;amp;A sites.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I tend to write as though I know what I'm writing about... And sometimes I do... But, you should always use your own judgement: question everything, read the links to supporting materials, and draw your own conclusions. I'm usually happy to discuss anything I've written, so don't hesitate to raise concerns or point out when something is unclear!&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;sup&gt;&lt;sub&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Whatsoever thy hand findeth to do, do it with thy might; for there is no work, nor device, nor knowledge, nor wisdom, in the grave, whither thou goest.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/sub&gt;&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="0" UpVotes="13" DownVotes="0" AccountId="620" />
  <row Id="8" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:06:48.457" DisplayName="Gabe" LastAccessDate="2015-03-19T02:03:09.250" Views="0" UpVotes="1" DownVotes="0" AccountId="5960" />
  <row Id="9" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:07:35.310" DisplayName="mmmmmpie" LastAccessDate="2015-03-30T17:57:49.187" WebsiteUrl="http://nope@nope.com" Location="West Virginia" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Oracle DBA, Sys Admin, SQL Dev, and some radios and stuff.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="5034898" />
  <row Id="10" Reputation="3591" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:07:41.150" DisplayName="drs" LastAccessDate="2022-01-12T20:43:49.603" Location="Rochester, NY, USA" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Engage in &lt;a href=&quot;http://woodworking.stackexchange.com&quot;&gt;Woodworking&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="57" UpVotes="2710" DownVotes="2" AccountId="1597949" />
  <row Id="11" Reputation="4798" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:07:41.540" DisplayName="Steven" LastAccessDate="2022-08-17T13:54:36.727" WebsiteUrl="http://www.twitter.com/sberkovitz" Location="Toronto, Canada" Views="49" UpVotes="497" DownVotes="15" AccountId="79558" />
  <row Id="12" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:07:54.307" DisplayName="Mike" LastAccessDate="2015-03-17T15:07:54.307" Location="Earth, TX" Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="154660" />
  <row Id="13" Reputation="631" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:09:10.383" DisplayName="rgmrtn" LastAccessDate="2022-02-23T14:45:54.897" WebsiteUrl="" Location="62º 28'N, 114º 22' W" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;sans tache; im certifiable&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="4" UpVotes="10" DownVotes="0" AccountId="3872225" />
  <row Id="14" Reputation="835" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:09:14.263" DisplayName="Joe" LastAccessDate="2022-07-27T16:58:34.473" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;SAS Programmer/Developer/Analyst/buzzword, when I'm not parenting a pair of rambunctious little boys.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;#SOreadytohelp&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="13" UpVotes="31" DownVotes="0" AccountId="1780022" />
  <row Id="15" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:09:19.203" DisplayName="Chris Farmer" LastAccessDate="2016-01-05T13:13:25.113" WebsiteUrl="http://cfarmerga.myopenid.com/" Location="Nashville, TN" AboutMe="Always happy, never blue." Views="0" UpVotes="3" DownVotes="0" AccountId="323" />
  <row Id="16" Reputation="173" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:09:25.003" DisplayName="Markie" LastAccessDate="2017-02-14T14:31:50.920" Location="UK" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Website developer&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="2" UpVotes="3" DownVotes="0" AccountId="2321310" />
  <row Id="17" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2015-03-17T15:09:50.447" DisplayName="Lumi" LastAccessDate="2015-04-11T01:46:50.457" Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="3780251" />
</users>
```

I was trying to parse the above xml file in order to load it to a csv and I was getting a NullType Error Traceback. I know a lot of questions were being asked about the same issue but i think the xml files in the questions asked here were somehow different to mine. Not that I am sure how an xml file look like. But here is the code.

```
# Importing the required libraries
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd
  
cols = ["row Id", "Reputation", "CreationDate", "DisplayName", "LastAccessDate", "WebsiteUrl", "Location", "AboutMe", "Views", "UpVotes", "DownVotes", "AccountId"]
rows = []
  
# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('Users.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

for r in root.findall("users"):
    
    print(rows)
        
    rowId = i.find("row Id").text
    print('Row Id: ' + str(rowId))
    reputation = i.find("Reputation").text
    creationDate = i.find("Creationdate").text
    displayname = i.find("Displayname").text
    lastAccessDate = i.find("LastAccessDate").text
    websiteUrl = i.find("WebsiteUel").text
    location = i.find("Location").text
    aboutMe = i.find("AboutMe").text
    views = i.find("Views").text
    upVotes = i.find("UpVotes").text
    downVotes = i.find("DownVotes").text
    accountId = i.find("AccountId").text
            
    rows.append({"rowId": rowId,
                "Reputation": reputation,
                "Creationdate": creationdate,
                "Displayname": displayname,
                "LastAccessDate": lastAccessDate,
                "WebsiteUrl": websiteUrl,
                "Location": location,
                "AboutMe": aboutMe,
                "Views": views,
                "UpVotes": upVotes,
                "DownVotes": downVotes,
                "AccountId": accountId
                })


            
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('users1.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need a `csv` as an output and not a SS ? The field `AboutMe` holds html content.

Anyways, since you need all the fields, no need to hardcode them :

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import chain

root = ET.parse("Users.xml").getroot()

data = [dict(r.items()) for r in root.findall(".//row")]  # or simply root
    
with open("Users.csv", mode="w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    
    flds = dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable([r.keys() for r in root])).keys()
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=",", fieldnames=flds) # adjust if needed

    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(data)
```

Or since you're using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can simply [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), then make a csv (*or SpreadSheet*).

```py
pd.read_xml("Users.xml").to_csv("Users.csv") # or to_excel("Users.xlsx")
```

Comment: The whole thing started when I need an sql file to practice sql. I don't know why but it seems sql file is not that easy to come by. I have searched kaggle and other data sites i have no luck of finding any sql file. My search led me here(stackoverflow) in a thread where someone suggest to another member looking for the sql dataset to looked at a link leading to where I downloaded the xml file. And so here I am.

Comment: So, I am not sure what I need at this point. What an SS file and offcourse i saw the html tags too and I was worried at first, but I said let me try and see what come up. Could the html elements lead cause problem? What do you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: I tried your code the first one you wrote using dict and some csv did not work as I did not have csv installed yet and I tried the second one you suggested using pandas.read_xml.to_csv(), it worked. I have no doubt that the first will also work.

Comment: The first one should work too. the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module is a *builit-in*. No need to install it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Timeless. I have issue with loading the csv file to a table in a mysql database. It is uploading the data but when why run a SELECT query on the table what I am seeing are all NULL. I don't know whether I need to create another thread for that.

Comment: Yes, that would be more suited for a separate question (*pure csv & SQL*). I'm not familiar with `SQL` but maybe you need to check/change the delimiter of the imported `csv`.

Comment: Oh? I don't know it is inbuilt. Perhaps I type something wrong. Let me go and try it then. It is good to have options.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `find` when the keys you are looking for are attributes on each element that use the `dict.get` api:

```py
# Iterate over the root directly
for child in root:
    print(rows)

    # get the attributes like this
    rowId = element.get('Id')
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) for reference on this.

`element.find` expects that there are children under `element`, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Thanks you really armed with something I have no knowledge of. However when I tried it this what I got.    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\loadXml_2_csv.py", line 16, in <module>
    rowId = i.get("row Id").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: You don't need the `.text`. The tag *name* is `row`, the attribute you want is `id`. Do `i.get('Id')`

Comment: Wow. I see it now. I think this also explain why I was noot able to load it to the database. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score -1):

Try powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$rows = $doc.Descendants("row")

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($row in $rows)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
   foreach($att in $row.Attributes())
   {
      Write-Host $att.Name.LocalName $att.Value
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $att.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $att.Value
      Write-Host "here : " $newRow 
   }
$newRow
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table | Export-CSV -path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't know what powershell is but after some googling I come to understand that it involves command-line shell and I was thinking this is some javascript tricks from you. Anuway, this powershell of a thing seems like a nice tool to have in my skills armoury as a would be programmer. I will have a loo at it. But for now, I don't think this is going to help me as I understand nothing from the above. Thanks for exposing something I oblivious to. I will learn it. Thanks.

Comment: Powershell comes with windows and is an enhanced command line utility.  It is written in Net Library and is very powerful.  From Start in Windows just type powershell.  My code uses the Net Xml Linq Library which is very similar to java.